# VirtualBox: get access to command prompt of Windows host from Linux guest

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh, virtualbox

I have a remote Windows computer that serves as host for Linux (Debian 9) running as guest inside VirtualBox. I have access to the guest Linux (which is part of a VPN) via SSH from my local machine. This way sometimes I need to be able to run Windows commands on the remote host via the remote guest. For example I need to run `chkdsk /f E:` for an attached USB drive. Is there a way to start guest VM enabling some sort of communication channel to the Windows host's command prompt?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on networking config from host to guest.
Assuming you have a bridged network and you know the IP of the host you can use SSH to forward RDP port of the host. This has been covered:

https://serverfault.com/questions/200249/how-to-tunnel-windows-remote-desktop-through-ssh-using-a-linux-box#200255

Comment: Good point, thank you! But is there a way for something more lightweight, text based, like SSH? I don't need the whole Desktop access - only command prompt...

Comment: You will need to run an ssh server on the host as well. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows
Depending on firewall config you may be able to connect to windows host directly or by forwarding ports in the same way as for RDP.

Comment: It's important to note that Windows 10 has an built in SSH server which can be utilized (in Developer mode) with case-sensitive username (second part of the `whoami` output, but in proper case, like IEUser). Even `bash` is available.